# The public folder was created on Outlook did not display on Address Book

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, active-directory, address-book, public-folders

In my Outlook, I created some public folders, and other users (within the same exchange server) saw them. But, when I click to drop down Address Book on Outlook, I cannot see the public folders here.

[image]

I checked them on the Exchange, and they still existed on it.
[image]

Then I thought the public folders displayed on the Address Book drop down list gotten data from Active Directory (AD). So, I checked them on AD. And i saw all item of Address Book drop down list gotten from AD, not Exchange. I think so.

[image]

Now, I misunderstand about some things below, Could you give me an explaination about:

1. Why does not my public folders does display on Address Book drop down list?
2. The name "Public Folders" on Exchange server and "Public Folders" on AD are different? I thought data from "Public Fodlers" on Exchange will be synced with "Public Fodlers" on AD, but following the 1st image, I am wrong, maybe
3. Do I need to config somethings on Exchange or AD to display my Public Folder (in Outlook) on Address Book drop down list?

**UPDATED 1: The information of the tabs after seleting properites a public folder**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook right-click one of these contact Public Folders, click **Properties...** and follow the **Outlook Address Book** tab. Make sure that **Show this folder as an e-mail Address Book** option is enabled. Also check its name there:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see Outlook Address Book tab as you said. I try to do it on Outlook 2010, 2013, but I can see three tabs: General, Home Page and Summary. Could you take a screen shot, please!

Comment: Updated the answer. This is strange that you can't see this tab. Also this is strange that you can't see at least "Permissions" tab - this is mandatory on all Public Folders.

Comment: Yes, This is very strange. I have updated the photos about three tabs. Please see them and what your opinion is about the issue. Do I need any special permissions? In additional, the account "thinguyen@qasus.com" belongs to Administrator group on Exchange server